# How do I prevent java.io.tmpdir from using the shortened DOS style filenames?

Tags: java, windows, temp

We are running into an issue where the path returned by System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") uses the DOS style shortened names.  "user.home" does NOT do that.

```
System.out.println("home=" + System.getProperty("user.home"));
System.out.println("tmpdir=" + System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
```

is resulting in:

```
home=C:\Users\LongUserName
tmpdir=C:\Users\LONGUS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

When our code later builds a path from that, some methods can't access the file.
I'd rather not bypass java.io.tmpdir and build the temp path from user.home.

Comment: It uses [`GetTempPathW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppathw) under the hood, so maybe you can change one of the environment variables `TMP`, `TEMP`, or `USERPROFILE`?

Comment: The `TMP` and `TEMP` environment variables use the short names of directories if present. Generating these names is optional with NTFS. This legacy compatibility feature can be disabled. Existing short names can be removed as well, but that's risky since applications may be using short names. The best approach would be to convert the path back via [`GetLongPathNameW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlongpathnamew).

Comment: so, it sounds more like a JVM bug that needs to be fixed.